GATT server connection via BLE breaking/not establishing
I'm working on a project for my internship where the goal is to make a mobile app which will read ECG data from a heart rate monitor and display it. However, I'm working with on the project with another person and our different approaches and not so good communication has led to some problems.
#include "bluetooth_ecg_wrapper.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "ecg.h"
#include "uart_ecg_data_provider.h"

#include <memory>

constexpr const char* MAIN_TAG = "Main";
constexpr std::uint32_t kTaskStackSize{2048};
    constexpr unsigned int kTaskUxPriority{1};

extern "C" void app_main(void) {
    ESP_LOGD(MAIN_TAG, "Application startup");
    std::size_t mtu_data_size = 62; 
    ECGDataQueue data_queue;

    auto uartDataProvider = std::make_unique<ecg::provider::UartECGDataProvider>(CONFIG_EMULATE_UART_GPIO_TX, CONFIG_EMULATE_UART_GPIO_RX);
    ecg::ECG ecg(std::move(uartDataProvider), mtu_data_size); 

    BluetoothECGWrapper bt_ecg_wrapper{};

    ecg.StartGatheringECGData(kTaskStackSize, kTaskUxPriority);
    data_queue = ecg.GetECGDataQueue();
    //uint16_t dummy_data = 5;
    //while(1)
    // {
    //     vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(2000));
    //     bt_ecg_wrapper.send_data(dummy_data);
    //     dummy_data++;
    // }
    while(1)
    {
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(100));
        bt_ecg_wrapper.send_data(data_queue.front());
        data_queue.pop();
    }
}

This is the main file. The thing is that when I run this code the device will sometimes not connect, sometimes connect and disconnect after a few seconds or connect and not disconnect at all which would be the rarest case. When I use the dummy data loop and comment out the lines ecg.StartGatheringECGData(kTaskStackSize, kTaskUxPriority); and data_queue = ecg.GetECGDataQueue(); the app works fine with dummy data. So the problem here is that the other person used xCreateTask to make a task for polling the data while I haven't used that in my bluetooth setup functions.
Bluetooth functions:
BluetoothECGWrapper::BluetoothECGWrapper()
{
    bluetooth_initialize();
    bluetooth_setup();
}

void BluetoothECGWrapper::bluetooth_initialize()
{
    if (!bt_initialized)
    {
        nvs_flash_init();
        esp_bt_controller_config_t bt_cfg = BT_CONTROLLER_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
        esp_bt_controller_init(&bt_cfg);
        esp_bt_controller_enable(ESP_BT_MODE_BLE);
        esp_bluedroid_init();
        esp_bluedroid_enable();
        bt_initialized = true;
    }
}

void BluetoothECGWrapper::bluetooth_setup()
{
    if (!bt_setup_done)
    {
        esp_ble_gatts_register_callback(esp_gatts_cb);
        esp_ble_gap_register_callback(esp_gap_cb);
        esp_ble_gatts_app_register(PROFILE_APP_ID);
        esp_ble_gatt_set_local_mtu(250);
        bt_setup_done = true;
    }
}

Data functions:
void ECG::StartGatheringECGData(std::uint32_t kTaskStackSize, unsigned int kTaskUxPriority)
{
    xTaskCreate(PollTask, "ECGPollTask", kTaskStackSize, this, kTaskUxPriority, kTaskPXCreatedTask);
}

void ECG::PollTask(void* pv_parameters)
{
    ECG ecg = static_cast<ECG >(pv_parameters);
    while (true)
    {
        ecg->ecg_data_provider_->PollECGData();
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(100));
    }
}

bool UartECGDataProvider::PollECGData()
{
    esp_err_t ret = soft_uart_receive(*soft_uart_port_, receive_buffer_.data(), kExpectedReadSize);
    if (ret == ESP_OK)
    {
        parseECGData();
        return true;
    }
    else{
        ESP_LOGE(kUartEcgDataProviderTag, "Failed to receive UART data");
        return false; 
    }
}
void UartECGDataProvider::parseECGData()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < receive_buffer_.max_size(); ++i)
    {
        if (kStartByte == receive_buffer_[i])
        {
            const auto data_length = receive_buffer_[i + 1];
            const auto end_package_data_idx = i + 2 + (data_length * 2);

            if (isPackageValid(end_package_data_idx))
            {
                const auto start_package_data_idx = i + 2;
                parseEcgPackage(start_package_data_idx, end_package_data_idx);
                i = end_package_data_idx + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
bool UartECGDataProvider::isPackageValid(const std::size_t end_idx)
{
    return end_idx < kExpectedReadSize && kEndByte == receive_buffer_[end_idx];
}

void UartECGDataProvider::parseEcgPackage(const std::size_t start_index, const std::size_t end_index)
{
    for (std::size_t i = start_index; i < end_index; i += 2)
    {
        const std::uint16_t ecg_data_element = (receive_buffer_[i] << 8) + receive_buffer_[i + 1];
        ESP_LOGD(kUartEcgDataProviderTag, "Deserialized data element: %u", ecg_data_element);
        InvokeCallback(ecg_data_element);
    }
}

My attempt at solving this was creating my own tasks for bluetooth functions where I placed them in this priority: bluetooth_initialize()>bluetooth_setup()>PollTask() but when I ran it, it made it even worse and the GATT server doesn't even open meaning my initialize and setup functions don't even trigger.The problem isn't up to the mobile app itself because the same problem occurs when connecting through Punch Through. Any ideas how to solve this or what could specifically be causing this behavior?
